# Can't recognize destructured map value names from function argument's inside a when-let

Tags: clojure

I get this Compilation Error saying : `Invalid token: function-name`

```
(defn execute-task-from-message
  "Parses the message dictionary, gets the function-name and arguments-list
   and applys the function on the arguments"
  [{function-name: "function-name"
    arguments-list: "arguments-list"} msg]
  (when-let [task (ns-resolve
                   *ns*
                   (symbol
                   (str task-namespace function-name)))]
    (apply task arguments-list)))
```

What's going wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some extra `:`s in your argument destructuring pehaps? If you include a bit of the stack trace and a bit more context I may be able to be more specific:

```
user> (def task-namespace "where-does-this-come-from")
#'user/task-namespace
user> (defn execute-task-from-message
          "Parses the message dictionary, gets the function-name and arguments-list
           and applys the function on the arguments"
        [{function-name "function-name"
          arguments-list "arguments-list"} msg]
          (when-let [task (ns-resolve *ns*
                            (symbol 
                               (str task-namespace function-name)))]
           (apply task arguments-list))) 

#'user/execute-task-from-message
```